# Sorting Classification by another field

Tags: qgis, symbology, classification, sorting

I am currently using the QGIS software. I use rule-based classification to extract the monetary values from a field and display them as symbols. For map legend purposes I need to concatenate the dollar symbol, but upon concatenating them, the QGIS software sorted them as string characters. I used color ramps based from the monetary value, so wrong sorting of the symbology would mean wrong representation Is there a way to sort the concatenated classification based on the monetary value.

[image]

Comment: "for map legend purposes I need to concatenate the dollar symbol" - I somehow doubt that.

Answer (score 2):

(You can just drag and drop to change the order, but setting all colors will be difficult)

If you have many values you can:

1. Set the symbol using a categorized renderer using only the numeric field.
2. Then use pyqgis to change all the labels to $+the value:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("hexgrid")[0] #Create a layer object. Change hexgrid to the name of your layer
old_renderer = layer.renderer() #Fetch the QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer object

new_renderer = old_renderer.clone() #Copy it to create a new renderer
new_renderer.deleteAllCategories() #Delete all categories

for oldcat in old_renderer.categories(): #For each of the old/active categories
    oldcat.setLabel('$'+oldcat.label()) #Set its label to $ + the current label (numeric value)
    new_renderer.addCategory(oldcat) #Add the category to the new emptied renderer

layer.setRenderer(new_renderer) #Apply the new renderer with the modified lables to the layer
```

[image]

Comment: It would be handy to have an expression editor for legend labels.

Comment: @Matt: I agree at 100%. And to be able to render it as html… for exemple, I classified species points with the french name, but the legend should be « french name (latin name) »… and the rule is that Latin name must be in italic!